# Indentation issues with emacs ess

Tags: emacs, indentation, ess

I have used Emacs ESS for quite a few years for Latex, R, Python, and SAS and pretty happy with it. One issue concerns me in SAS programming is the block indentation, of the do loop and macro definition. By default, the indentation for do loop in *ESS* is as follows,

```SAS
data test
    do i = 1 to 3;
        x = i ** 3;
        output;
        end;
run;
```

However, I would prefer the following indentation,

```SAS
data test;
    do i = 1 to 3;
        x = i ** 3;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Is there any easy way to get the second indentation by default in ESS/SAS?